# JavaScript - removeClass from matching img title?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making new question thread, because I wasn't clear and I agree with that.

So, I have clickable `item-cards`, if you click on one the class name changes to `selected` and it also adds the item which you click on to the `cart`. Each cart item has `X` behind, if you click it, it will remove the item from the cart, but it doesn't remove the `selected` part. If I added there that it would remove that class, then it removed it from all items. Example, if I add 2 items in cart and I deleted one from the cart, then it removed the `selected` class from all, but how could I make it so it would only removes it from, which has same img title? Here are some examples:

Selected Item HTML

```
<li class="col 2 zoomIn animated" style="padding: 1%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; animation-delay: 0s;">
<div class="card item-card waves-effect waves-light red lighten-1 white-text selected-item" style="margin: 0%; min-height: 295px; width: 245.438px; border-radius: 15px; height: 245px;" id="2761454276">
    <div class="iteam" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: left">Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web</div>
    <div class="condition" style="text-align: left;text-size:13px">Field Tested</div>
    <div class="center-align" style="padding:6%">
        <img title="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" draggable="false" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf0ebcZThQ6tCvq4iSqODxMajum25V4dB8xLjD9tjwjgK1_kZoYT30ctKVegM7NFyGrwK5yee90ZDt6ZmazHNluCQ8pSGKMl3kzfs/200fx200">
        <div class="" 'floatvalue'="">Float: 0.11503319442272186
            <div class="bitskinscomp" style="font-weight: normal;font-size:12px">BitSkins Price: $110.52 (You save: $-39.06)</div>
            <div class="buyer-price center-align">$149.58</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code, if you click on X

```
$("#itemcart span").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove()
```

Code how X is being added

```
$("#itemcart div").each(function(){
if( $(this).children().length > 0){

} else{
$(this).append($("<span> X</span>"));
}
});
```

Clicking on item-card

```
 $(".item-card").click(function() {
       var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
       var replaced = itemnume.split(' ').join('_');
       replaced = replaced.split('(').join('');
       replaced = replaced.split(')').join('');
       replaced = replaced.split('|').join('');

       if ($(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
           $("#" + replaced).last().remove();
       } else {
        $("#itemcart").append($("<div id=" + replaced + ">" + itemnume + "</div>"));
        $("#itemcart div").each(function(){
        if( $(this).children().length > 0){

        } else{
        $(this).append($("<span> X</span>"));
        }
        });

        $("#itemcart span").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove()
            $(".item-card").removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
            calculateTotal();
        });
       }
       $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");

       calculateTotal();
   });
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're adding item to cart or html of the cart item?

Comment: Tried this here: https://jsfiddle.net/1tkvjsLv/ Can't find the X, please provide the code.

Comment: No, It doesn't add X there. X comes into Item-cart that code is just if you click on the item which will be added to the cart. That's when item is selected.

Comment: You haven't `itemcart` as `id` attribute in your HTML snippet and the `class` names are `item-cart`. You should provide a consistent test case demonstrating what happens and what doesn't.

Comment: You might want `$('.item-cart div')`

Comment: Here's a GIF for that. I hope it makes it more understandable. Like you see on the gif, if you click item it goes into cart and if you click X then it removes that "selected class as well or let's call it red". But if I added 2 items to the cart and example clicked on Asiimov X, then it removed that Asiimov, but removed BOTH Red's but it has to remove Asiimov selected class. https://gyazo.com/93fcd52733b7bdd1de506498a0c15a61

Comment: A minimal but completely runnable code example would be more helpful.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know code to delete that item selected from the item which X was clicked. At the moment I got code so it deletes from all if you click X.. Here's code which removes those item-selected from ALL items atm.. `$(".item-card").removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Hmm, I can't I can't get those clickable item-cards working on JSFiddle.

Comment: If someone can't understand maybe you could tell me a part which you can't understand, so I'll try to explain that part again :).

Comment: Just include the code that add item to cart, that's missing.

Comment: Edited first post, added full function if you click on that item in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, save selected item in data and get it on click:

```
$(".item-card").click(function() {
   var itemnume = $(this).find("img").attr("title");
   var replaced = itemnume.split(' ').join('_');
   replaced = replaced.split('(').join('');
   replaced = replaced.split(')').join('');
   replaced = replaced.split('|').join('');

   if ($(this).hasClass('selected-item')) {
       $("#" + replaced).last().remove();
   } else {
    var cart_item = $("<div id=" + replaced + ">" + itemnume + "</div>");
    $("#itemcart").append(cart_item);
    $("#itemcart div").each(function(){
    if( $(this).children().length > 0){

    } else{
    $(this).append($("<span> X</span>"));
    }
    });
    var self = $(this);
    cart_item.on('click', 'span', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove()
        self.removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
        calculateTotal();
    });
   }
   $(this).toggleClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");

   calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: I've tested your code, but it still removes selected item from all classes which have that selected-item :/. It would have to only remove from that which I click X on, example: In cart I got Banana & Apple, then I click X on Banana it should remove that selected-item from Banana, but not from Apple.

Comment: @JacobSeen Try to change this line `item.data('item', $(this));` instead of `closest` I've just notice that `this` is already .item-card element.

Comment: Code which removes that element is here: $("#itemcart").on('click', 'span', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.data('item').removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
    parent.remove();
}); or am I wrong?

Comment: look at updated answer I've changed what I save in data('item') inside `$(".item-card").click` `item.data('item', $(this));` instead of item.data('item', $(this).closest('.item-card'));

Comment: Also, You have left in my code which removes all those classes. `$(".item-card").removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");`

Comment: Just tested it after disabling my part, it does remove from item cart, but doesn't remove selected class :/

Comment: See updated answer. I've just notice that you don't need that data thing because you can reference the object from parent function.

Comment: Interesting, this code actually should work, but still removes from all classes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a running snippet with fake entries. You have to adapt indentifiers to your dynamic code.

Delegate event listening to the `<ul>` element. Listen to clicks on the `<ul><li><div><span>` element and remove the `<li>` 2 parents upward.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="item-store">
      <li class="col 2 zoomIn animated" style="padding: 1%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; animation-delay: 0s;">
          <div class="card item-card waves-effect waves-light red lighten-1 white-text selected-item" style="margin: 0%; min-height: 295px; width: 245.438px; border-radius: 15px; height: 245px;" id="1000">
              <div class="iteam" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: left">
                  Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web
              </div>
              <div class="condition" style="text-align: left;text-size:13px">
                  Field Tested
              </div>
              <div class="center-align" style="padding:6%">
                  <img title="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" draggable="false" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf0ebcZThQ6tCvq4iSqODxMajum25V4dB8xLjD9tjwjgK1_kZoYT30ctKVegM7NFyGrwK5yee90ZDt6ZmazHNluCQ8pSGKMl3kzfs/200fx200">
                  <div class="" 'floatvalue'="">
                      Float: 0.11503319442272186
                      <div class="bitskinscomp" style="font-weight: normal;font-size:12px">
                          BitSkins Price: $110.52 (You save: $-39.06)
                      </div>
                      <div class="buyer-price center-align">
                          $149.58
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col 2 zoomIn animated" style="padding: 1%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; animation-delay: 0s;">
          <div class="card item-card waves-effect waves-light red lighten-1 white-text selected-item" style="margin: 0%; min-height: 295px; width: 245.438px; border-radius: 15px; height: 245px;" id="1001">
              <div class="iteam" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: left">
                  Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web
              </div>
              <div class="condition" style="text-align: left;text-size:13px">
                  Field Tested
              </div>
              <div class="center-align" style="padding:6%">
                  <img title="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" draggable="false" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf0ebcZThQ6tCvq4iSqODxMajum25V4dB8xLjD9tjwjgK1_kZoYT30ctKVegM7NFyGrwK5yee90ZDt6ZmazHNluCQ8pSGKMl3kzfs/200fx200">
                  <div class="" 'floatvalue'="">
                      Float: 0.11503319442272186
                      <div class="bitskinscomp" style="font-weight: normal;font-size:12px">
                          BitSkins Price: $110.52 (You save: $-39.06)
                      </div>
                      <div class="buyer-price center-align">
                          $149.58
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
//Code, if you click on X

$(".item-store").on('click', '.item-card span', (function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}));

//Code how X is being added

//$(".item-cart div").each(function()
$(".item-card ").each(function()
{
  if( $(this).children().length > 0){
    $(this).append($("<span> x</span>"));
  } else{
    $(this).append($("<span> X</span>"));
  }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code will remove it from #itemcart & the selected class as well? `$(".item-store").on('click', '.item-card span', (function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}));`

Comment: When you dynamically add new items, you should consider usage of listener delegation. That means some element e.g. the `<ul>` handles the listener but is listening for events from other elements inside its container, even from elements added *later* than the listener. I've added code to your first incomplete example and named the `<ul>` class 'item-store'. You should unterstand the principle and be able to adapt it to your document structure not exposed here.

Comment: your code is all wrong the item need to remove from #itemcart not from .item-card, .item-card need to have classes removed.

Comment: This code removes list items from the `ul` what does make semantically sense and is working. The code provided was just a list with a single item-card showing some image of a knife.